# How can I add a hidden folder during creation of a WAR file.

Tags: eclipse, svn, web-applications, war

I am developing a dynamic web application and exporting the WAR file to deploy it on the Server. My project directory in Eclipse has a hidden folder named .svn which I want to include in the WAR file being generated.
For Example: I have **ProjectName/.svn** folder, which I want to include in **WebContent/WEB-INF/classes** folder during creation of the WAR file. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

Comment: why do you want to do this ? that folder is for subversion version control, it has nothing to do with the functioning of the webapp

Comment: That folder is deliberately not included, as NimChimpsky says it is for version control and hidden, it should never be on your webserver.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I am using the svn revision number from the file .svn/entries to calculate the version number of the application. This changes the version number each time a different version of the source tree is checked out from SVN. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could do this using another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I also *don't understand the reason*, but this is how you can do that:

If you have a dynamic web project, than you have a config file which is called `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`. If you add a line into it like below, you can instruct Eclipse to build other stuff into the WAR. Deploy path is the relative path inside the WAR, source path is a relative path inside your project. If you link an external folder into your project, you can even include that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="bla">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
        <!--your extra stuff is this line-->
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/.svn" source-path="/.svn"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="bla"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/bla/build/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

I did not try it, but it should work I guess.